# Jmeter with jenkins to set SLA

Tags: jenkins, jmeter

I am integrating jmeter with jenkins.

I would like to set the SLA for each of the transactions and make the build success/fail according to the SLA.

How do I do this from jenkins?

Answer (score 0):

You can Jenkins [Performance Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Performance+Plugin) to integrate with JMeter and define failed/unstable % range according to your SLA. You can follow [blazemeter tutorial](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/continuous-integration-101-how-run-jmeter-jenkins).

> The Performance Plugin displays statistics, trends and can also be used to mark builds as failed based on results.